# How to close Tomcat socket to stop listening for new HTTP requests?

Tags: java, sockets, spring-boot, tomcat, port

I have a Spring Boot application with Zuul and I have a requirement where I need to stop listening for new HTTP requests while still being able to process the already recieved requests.

Also is it possible to reopen the port again.?

Comment: This sounds like a very bad client experience. It would be better to return a 307-Temporary redirect pointing to a some static content that describes the situation.or a 503 - Server is (temporarily) unavailable. You can code the logic for this into a servlet filter that sits in front of your servlets, rest endpoints, or whatever.

Comment: Did you try accessing your server by JMX and disabling the Connector ? Please note I didn't try myself, I don't know if this works.

Comment: @EugèneAdell


I tried two approaches:

**1** Tried pausing Catalina
**2** Tried pausing Connector

The problem with the above two approaches is that the request is still being received(till Catalina or Connector) and some kind of processing is under progress. If this happens during graceful shutdown, this processing of new requests is going to delay the shutdown.


@ Tom Drake
The reason I listed above is also the reason I do not want to use any filters.
And somehow want to disable/pause the socket.

Comment: @RohitGupta Maybe try MaxConnections=0 and acceptCount=0 throught JMX, more info on the Connetor parameters [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/http.html)

Comment: @EugèneAdell I tried setting MaxConnections=0 and acceptCount=0. But then I digged into code and found out that 0 is considered as an invalid value. So when I set these values to 0 they change to default values.

Comment: What OS are you running ? On Linux you can play with the **firewall** to block a service/port, and all established connections would be kept, then you can open again your service/port. It has nothing to see with application development (programming), so maybe should you move your question to ServerFault.